# Xampp PhpMyAdmin Import Incredibly Slow localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I've recently set up XAMPP on my local machine, and everything seems to be working well.  MySQL queries seem to be able to retrieve data quite quickly (performing `LIKE` matches on over 3000 queries 3000 times, for example).

However, I'm noticing huge delays in PhpMyAdmin, and more specifically when trying to import files.  A 1MB CSV is what I'm trying to import, which is 22,000 lines in total.

At this office my upload speed registers at 0.26Mb, yet I'm able to import an identical CSV to an online version of my database in a fraction of the time it takes to import it locally.

I've tried disabling all AV and firewalls, editing `hosts` to uncomment the localhost IP etc, editing `my.ini` `query-cache` settings, and increased the upload and post sized in `php.ini`.  I've also had to increase `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in an effort to manage to import the file at all, as it otherwise times out.

Does anyone have any advice on how to rectify this?  I am using Windows 7 Pro SP1, 64 Bit, i5-2400 3.10 Ghz CPU, 8.0 GB RAM.

Many Thanks

Comment: do you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as address? Try using 127.0.0.1 in connection string.

Comment: Hi Dexa, I have tried using both.  They both cause timeouts unless I break the CSV down into two sections.